# How to monitor keys that are generated under “New Application Registration” for Azure AD Web App / API apps?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-account

My customer is building a ton of applications using Azure AD as the IdP for their tenant.  Managing at a scale is going to be a challenge for them as they have different keys expiring at different times.
**How can they monitor the keys that are being generated at a scale?**

Note: My initial thought was to pull the data via Graph and put into a monitoring tool like Splunk/PowerBi – but couldn’t locate the graph information via https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#. 
**Is this exposed via aad.portal.azure.com from a list view by date?**

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [Graph API](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net) (https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications) to query the applications entity and then read the keyCredentials (certificates) and passwordCredentials (secrets) attributes.

Another option would be to use Powershell:

```
$apps=Get-AzureADApplication
foreach ($app in $apps)
{
    foreach ($pw in $app.passwordcredentials)
    {
        write-output "$($app.displayname),$($pw.enddate)"
    }
    foreach ($ky in $app.keycredentials)
    {
        write-output "$($app.displayname),$($ky.enddate)"
    }
}
```

In either case take into account that not only applications can have secrets/certificates configured, but also service principals.

Comment: Thanks andresm53. This is exactly what I was looking for.  I figured this would be under keycredentials but the keys created for the apps are under passwordcredentials.  The naming convention confused me.

Comment: @ChadHasbrook If you want Azure to support this feature you can vote the feedback at [this link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9392007-need-email-alert-option-when-keys-are-about-to-exp).